# How to highlight exact member information on click of a 3D modal member using javascript

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am working on Forge Revit 3D modal.
Rendering a 3D modal based on URNSourceFile.

Problem Statement :

We have a GUID (like "ad6dd74d-c919-432a-8404-0a17b7659df4") for all the members of the modal.

We have a table(not part of forge), in which all the members information including GUID is set.

We have a scenario like, On click of a member(beam) from the modal we need to highlight exact match row of GUID from the table.

Table List of rows is not part of forge viewer.
Please suggest on triggering point on click of a member(beam) to highlight a member row.

Please find the attached screenshot for the reference.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTOSg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you know the ID of the object you want to highlight, you highlight it in different ways, for example, by programmatically selecting it using [viewer.select](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#select-dbids-model-selectiontype), or giving the object a color tint using [viewer.setThemingColor](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#setthemingcolor-dbid-color-model-recursive).

To find an object (and its ID), there are also different ways. For example, you can find all objects containing a specific piece of text in their metadata using [viewer.search](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#search-text-onsuccesscallback-onerrorcallback-attributenames).